# Yii2: how to use two models in one view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a model called **Person.php** and a model called **Country.php**.
Then I have the view **Persons/create.php**

I included the model of the countries and I called **$modelCountry** but is it not working. I got the error:

> Undefined variable: modelCountry

This is the **model/Persons.php** file.

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Person */
/* @var $modelCountry app\models\Country */

?>
<div class="person-create">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput() ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelCountry, 'name')->textInput() ?>

        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create') ?>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Then I want to use the send button to send both models to the controller (controllers/PersonsController.php)

Comment: update you question and add  you controller/action code (your actionCreate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the variable `modelCountry` to your view files

### In your controller action:

```
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelCountry' => $modelCountry,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

seems you want input two different model in a time
for this you don't need include the second model in view but in controller  you should create models for both the class .. pass to the createView  and properly manage the submitted  values then for last render the view

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Person();
    $modelCountry = new Country()

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post('Person') &&  ($modelCoutr->load(Yii::$app->request->post('Country'))  {
        $model->save();
        $modelCountry->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'modelCountry' => $modelCountry,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In you action view in render function add  the models you need

```
public function actionView($id)
{

    $yourModelCountry =  Country::find()->where(...)->one();

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'modelCountry' => $yourModelCountry , 
    ]);
}
```

then in your view you can refer both  using $model for model and $modelCountry for yourModelCountr